# modify a CSS file for Internet Explorer only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, frontend, cross-browser

I am looking for a way to modify my **style.css** file to target ONLY Internet Explorer browser (so without impacting my styles for Chrome & Firefox).

---

#### Example

**I want to the following style for Chrome & Firefox:**

```
.header .currency {margin: **-28px** 0px 0px 0px;}
```

**I want the following style for IE:**

```
.header .currency {margin: **-30px** 0px 0px 0px;}
```

---

#### Note

Posts exist for CSS modification on HTML file and this is not what I am looking for. Therefore please do not provide response if this is not link to .CSS file.

Answer (score 5):

#### IE6 to IE9

For versions of IE up to IE9, it's best to use [conditional stylesheets](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) :

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]> Internet Explorer 6 or less <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]> Internet Explorer 7 or less <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]> Internet Explorer 8 or less <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]> Internet Explorer 9 or less <![endif]-->
```

Conditional stylesheets are ignored by every browser except versions of IE that correspond with the condition.

#### IE10 to IE11

Unfortunately, IE10 and IE11 do not support conditional stylesheets. However, you can use the following CSS hack to target only those two browsers :

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   // Put your IE10+-specific CSS here
}
```

See [browserhacks.com](http://browserhacks.com/) for an overview of different ways to target specific browsers with CSS.

---

#### Note

For various reasons, it's recommended to write as little browser-specific CSS as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is use [conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx).

For example:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
load here your ie8.css
<![endif]-->
```

IF you want edit only CSS:

```
 /* IE css hack */
  margin-top: 10px\9 /* apply to all ie from 8 and below */
  *margin-top:10px;  /* apply to ie 7 and below */
  _margin-top:10px; /* apply to ie 6 and below */
```

Final mode, [@media hack](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/).